# lxml xsi:schemaLocation namespace URI validation issue

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces, cda

I'm trying to use `lxml.etree` to reproduce the CDA example found in the [CDA QuickStart Guide found here](http://www.lantanagroup.com/resources/free-tools/).

In particular, I'm running into issues with namespaces trying to recreate this element.

```
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:mif="urn:hl7-org:v3/mif" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 CDA.xsd">
```

The code I'm using is as follows

```
root = etree.Element('ClinicalDocument',
                    nsmap={None: 'urn:hl7-org:v3',
                           'mif': 'urn:hl7-org:v3/mif',
                           'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
                           '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}schemaLocation': 'urn:hl7-org:v3 CDA.xsd'})
```

The problem is with the `schemaLocation` entry in `nsmap`. `lxml` appears to be trying to validate the value and gives the error

```
ValueError: Invalid namespace URI u'urn:hl7-org:v3 CDA.xsd'
```

Am I specifying the `schemaLocation` value incorrectly? Is there a way to force `lxml` to accept any string value? Or is the value in the example simply intended to be a placeholder that I am supposed to replace with something else?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`nsmap` is a mapping of prefixes to namespace URIs. `urn:hl7-org:v3 CDA.xsd` is a valid value for the `xsi:schemaLocation`attribute, but it is not a valid namespace URI.

The solution to a similar question, [How to include the namespaces into a xml file using lxmf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46405690/407651), works here too. Use `QName` to create the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute.

```
from lxml import etree

attr_qname = etree.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "schemaLocation")

root = etree.Element('ClinicalDocument',
                     {attr_qname: 'urn:hl7-org:v3 CDA.xsd'},
                     nsmap={None: 'urn:hl7-org:v3',
                            'mif': 'urn:hl7-org:v3/mif',
                            'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
                            })
```

Comment: Thanks for digging this up, I had given up on finding the answer.